# Update MongoDB collection with $toLower or $toUpper

Tags: mongodb, database

I would like to convert the 'state' field for all 'Organization' to all UPPER case. So

'Ky' becomes 'KY'
'tX' becomes 'TX'
'ca' becomes 'CA'

why this doesn't work

`db.organizations.update(state:{ $exists : true }},{$set:{state:{ $toUpper : state }}}, false, true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put `toUpperCase()` like this:

```
"$set": { "state": doc.state.toUpperCase() } }
```

Comment: this answer is confusing and doesn't really make sense. What is "doc" and where does it come from? @Neil Lunn provides a more comprehensive answer

Answer (score 8):

The [**`$toLower`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/) and [**`$toUpper`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toUpper/) operators you reference are for use with the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) only, and by itself does not alter documents in a collection as the `.update()` statement does. Also it is not presently possible to reference the value of an existing field within an update statement to produce a new value.

What you need to do is "loop" the collection and make your changes:

```js
db.organizations.find({ "state": { "$exists": true } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    db.organizations.update(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        { "$set": { "state": doc.state.toUpperCase() } }
    );
});
```

With MongoDB 2.6 or greater you can make this a bit better with the bulk operations API:

```js
var bulk = db.organizations.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;

db.organizations.find({ "state": { "$exists": true } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { "state": doc.state.toUpperCase() } }
    );
    count++;
    if ( count % 500 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.organizations.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
        count = 0;
    }
});

if ( count > 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

While still basically looping the results, the writes are only sent to the database once every 500 documents or whatever you choose to set staying under the 16MB BSON limit for the operation.

Comment: none of them works. MongoDB says 'TypeError: doc.state.toUpper is not a function (shell):4'

Comment: @SomPoddar You must be typing something out differently. `toUpper()` is a JavaScript built in for string type objects. We have already checked that it exists so is there a possibility some of your data is in fact `null` or otherwise not a string? Are you in fact running this inside the `.forEach()` loop that declares the `doc` variable? The basic code is something that has been done thousands of times so it does work. Check what you are doing.

Comment: @NeilLunn The JavaScript built in is [`String.prototype.toUpperCase()`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.touppercase).

Answer (score 1):

The code below do exactly what you want in one step:

`db.organizations.updateMany( { state: { $exists : true } }, [ { $set: { state: { $toUpper: "$state" } } } ] );`